# How to append commands to a macro without expanding them

Tags: macros, expansion

I'm working on building an `expenses` package. The intention is to be able to write

```
\expense{someone}{something}{something a bit longer}{10}{GBP}
\expense{someone else }{something else}{something a bit longer}{11}{EUR}
\makeexpensetable
```

To do this, I am starting an internal `\allexpenses` macro

```
\def\allexpenses{}
```

Then each `\expense` command appends to that a `\writeexpense` command defined as

```
\newcommand{\writeexpense}[5]{%
    #1 & #2 & #4 \\ %
}
```

So that eventually the `\makeexpensetable` command will simply begin a table, then have an `\allexpenses` line containing all the rows and end the table.

My current `\expense` command is

```
\newcommand{\expense}[5]{%
    \edef\allexpenses{\allexpenses%
        \writeexpense{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }%
}
```

However, TeX is throwing errors due to the presence of the `\writeexpense` command inside. How do I stop that command from expanding? I'm guessing the answer has something to do with the correct use of a `\noexpand` command, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative, `@`-free solution:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\allexpenses{\writeexpense{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
```

There are also one or two *package*-free solutions, but they effectively reinvent the `\appto` wheel.  The problem is that `\edef` expands its contents recursively, and you only want the initial `\allexpenses` to be expanded *once*.  In fact, it's not `\noexpand` but `\unexpanded` that you want:

```
\edef\allexpenses{%
  \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\allexpenses}%
  \unexpanded{\writeexpense{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
}
```

This causes `\allexpenses` to be expanded once into whatever it contains, and then those contents to be protected from further expansion.  The first line is equivalent to `\expandonce\allexpenses`, where `\expandonce` is also defined in `etoolbox`.  The `eTeX`-free solution is to use a token register for this:

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\allexpenses \writeexpense{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\edef\allexpenses{\the\toks0}
```

Token registers were the original `\expandonce`, but since their assignment is not fully expandable, they are not always suitable where this eTeX-based macro is.

Comment: The first `\expandafter` in the second solution is redundant. The third solution is wrong because `\writeexpense` would be expanded! Just put it in `\toks0` beforehand.

Comment: Both the second and third solution would edef-expand `\writeexpense` and all its arguments, meaning no fragile commands (such as accented letters) could be used in the arguments

Comment: Fixed, @both of you.

Comment: Also some of us like solutions with as many @ as possible.

Comment: I put one in my comment just for you :)

Answer (score 5):

use `\g@addto@macro\allexpenses{\writeexpense{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}`
in a package file or between `\makeatletter` `\makeatother`