# \href is not working inside \xdef

Tags: macros, expansion

this is my first question here. I've already spent a substantial amount of time searching this before posting it here.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\test{First -- Void1}

\begin{document}
\xdef\test{\test\ \& Second -- Void2}
\test
\end{document}
```

which gives the desired output as:

[image: output]

But whenever I change my code as:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\test{First -- \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}

\begin{document}
\xdef\test{\test\ \& Second -- \href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks}}
\test
\end{document}
```

Latex gives an error & no output is produced of course.

I've done this replacement only for Void1, only for Void2 and for both (as in the 2nd snippet); but nothing worked.

Can anybody help me out with this. (**If \href doesn't work with \xdef I need an alternative to append urls to an existing string**)

Thanks.

Modified Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\newarray\Emails
\readarray{Emails}{abc@example.com&xyz@example.com&pqr@example.com&mno@example.com}
\def\test{}

\begin{document}
\multido{\idx=1+1}{4}{%
  \checkEmails(\idx)
  \noindent Email-\idx\ \ is \cachedata\\
  % Here I want some way to store the emails as href in that global macro '\test'
  % Something like --> \xdef\test{\unexpanded\expandafter{\test} \href{mailto:\cachedata}{\cachedata}}
  \xdef\test{\unexpanded\expandafter{\test} Normal-Text -- \cachedata, }%
}

\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the kernel command `\g@addto@macro`. Also package `etoolbox` offers some tools, e.g. the `\appto` macro.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107923/how-to-append-commands-to-a-macro-without-expanding-them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really want `\xdef`, because it can do really bad to your macros. In any case you don't really want to expand all the way through, which `\xdef` does.

There are already several ways for appending tokens to a parameterless macro:

```
\def\test{First -- Void1}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\test{\ \& Second -- \href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks}}
\makeatother
```

uses a method defined in the LaTeX kernel.

A slightly different approach, but it's mostly equivalent, is

```
\def\test{First -- Void1}

\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\test\expandafter{%
  \test\ \& Second -- \href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks}}
```

which is nearer to what you're trying to do. You see that the (global) redefinition of `\test` happens when `\test` in the replacement text has been already expanded.

With `\usepackage{etoolbox}` you have the alternatives

```
\def\test{First -- Void1}

\appto\test{\ \& Second -- \href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks}}
\gappto\test{\ \& Second -- \href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks}}
```

With `\appto` the action is local to the group where this happens, with `\gappto` the action is global (probably what you want).

---

For the `\multido` problem, you need something slightly different.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newarray\Emails
\readarray{Emails}{%
  \href{abc@example.com}{abc}&%
  \href{xyz@example.com}{xyz}&%
  \href{pqr@example.com}{pqr}&%
  \href{mno@example.com}{mno}}
\def\test{}

\begin{document}
\multido{\idx=1+1}{4}{%
  \checkEmails(\idx)
  \noindent Email-\idx\ \ is \cachedata\\
  \xdef\test{\unexpanded\expandafter{\test}
             Normal-Text --
             \unexpanded\expandafter{\cachedata}, }%
}

\test

\end{document}
```

I've added `\href` just to show that it works also with it. Use `arrayjobx` rather than `arrayjob` that conflicts with some important LaTeX commands.

Comment: your code worked, thanks. But the problem is I'm trying to do this inside a **\multido** loop, where any of the above tricks didn't work. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/HeYGv6y.jpg) is the screenshot of MWE taken from _Gummi_. This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @dibyendu I don't see what `\href` has to do with the addition.

Comment: Thanks egreg for patiently answering my questions. But now **href** is not working inside that _multido_. I've added the exact code that I'm working on at the bottom this time.